# Inject bean into custom validator

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I want to use one of the beans in a custom validator but keep getting null for the autowired field.

I found this link https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints which seems to be talking about what I intend to do.

"By default, the LocalValidatorFactoryBean configures a SpringConstraintValidatorFactory that uses Spring to create ConstraintValidator instances. This lets your custom ConstraintValidators benefit from dependency injection like any other Spring bean."

This paragraph makes me think it should just work out of the box ("by default)

```java
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CompanyValidator.class)
public @interface ValidCompany {
    String message() default "Invalid company.";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

```java
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class CompanyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidCompany, Long> {

    @Autowired
    private IdentityClient identityClient;

    public void initialize(ValidCompany constraint) {}

    public boolean isValid(@Valid Long value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return identityClient.getCompany(value).getContent() != null;
    }

}
```

IdentityClient is the bean I want to inject. It is a FeignClient thhat gives this validator access to a remote API to validate that the provided company ID exists.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I have tried the following without any change in behavior:

```java
@Configuration
public class ValidationConfig {

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor mvpp = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        mvpp.setValidator(validator());
        return mvpp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you configured a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`  as detailed in section 3.7.2. (which uses XML however you can can obviously do in Java config if required) https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring

Comment: Yes, I tried this as edited above. Although, I think it should not be necessary as the documentation describes this as the "default".